# Why is accessing an element of a large vector of structs in debug mode slower than accessing a smaller one?

Tags: vector, struct, rust

When I run this code:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Element {
    pub key: u64,
}

pub fn test1(u: usize) {
    let now = std::time::SystemTime::now();

    let tt = vec![Element { key: 0 }; u];
    for _ in 0..10000000 as u64 {
        if tt[155].key == 893472348628 {}
    }

    match now.elapsed() {
        Ok(elapsed) => {
            println!(
                "With struct, size of vec={}: Time elapsed: {}.{} seconds",
                u,
                elapsed.as_secs(),
                elapsed.subsec_nanos()
            );
        }
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Error: {:?}", e);
            panic!();
        }
    }
}

pub fn test2(u: usize) {
    let now = std::time::SystemTime::now();

    let tt = vec![0u64; u];
    for _ in 0..10000000 as u64 {
        if tt[155] == 893472348628 {}
    }

    match now.elapsed() {
        Ok(elapsed) => {
            println!(
                "With u64, size of vec={}: Time elapsed: {}.{} seconds",
                u,
                elapsed.as_secs(),
                elapsed.subsec_nanos()
            );
        }
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Error: {:?}", e);
            panic!();
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    test1(100000);
    test1(100000000);
    test2(100000);
    test2(100000000);
}
```

I get these results:

```
With struct, size of vec=100000: Time elapsed: 1.268881822 seconds
With struct, size of vec=100000000: Time elapsed: 12.470818140 seconds
With u64, size of vec=100000: Time elapsed: 1.171180429 seconds
With u64, size of vec=100000000: Time elapsed: 1.230393828 seconds
```

I do not see any reason why the second function call should be 10 times slower than the first one. I did compile it in **debug** mode since release mode ignored these lines:

```
if tt[155].key == 893472348628 {}
```

I have a 64bit Linux machine with 8GB of RAM, maybe it has something to do with that?

Comment: I'd like to commend you on the edits you've made to your post. The question is now in a *much* better state and concrete enough to be answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not accessing the element that takes time, but initializing the vector. Indeed, with your example I get:

```
With struct, size of vec=100000: Time elapsed: 0.594704815 seconds
With struct, size of vec=100000000: Time elapsed: 5.789152687 seconds
With u64, size of vec=100000: Time elapsed: 0.584137362 seconds
With u64, size of vec=100000000: Time elapsed: 0.586343084 seconds
```

If I initialize `now` after `tt` I get the following:

```
With struct, size of vec=100000: Time elapsed: 0.589499628 seconds
With struct, size of vec=100000000: Time elapsed: 0.583244899 seconds
With u64, size of vec=100000: Time elapsed: 0.584675666 seconds
With u64, size of vec=100000000: Time elapsed: 0.583518382 seconds
```

Initializing the vector takes linear time because every element needs to be initialized to `0` (or `Element { key: 0 }`).

As for why it's faster with `0` than `Element { key: 0 }`, let's have a look at how `vec!` works. [We can see it just calls `vec::from_elem`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/63739ab7b210c1a8c890c2ea5238a3284877daa3/src/liballoc/macros.rs#L48), which in turn [just calls `<T as SpecFromElem>::from_elem`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/d5f2745e7ccd247da50f0cb18318ac477e5bccbf/src/liballoc/vec.rs#L1438-L1455). What is this trait? Well, its default implementation basically looks like:

```
let mut v = Vec::with_capacity(n);
v.extend_with(n, ExtendElement(elem));
```

But there are also a [bunch of special cases](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/d5f2745e7ccd247da50f0cb18318ac477e5bccbf/src/liballoc/vec.rs#L1494-L1505) including one for `0u64`! This one uses `RawVec::with_capacity_zeroed(n)`. No doubt this special case is where the speed comes from.

Comment: Presumably in release mode, the optimizer "sees through" the `Element` struct and makes it into a literal `u64`, thus unlocking the same special casing?

Comment: I would certainly hope so.